# Can I get a copy of CVS differences to my local drive?

Tags: netbeans, project, cvs, vcs-checkout

I cannot access the CVS account at home, but I would like to checkout the cvs repo and take it home with the ability to go through every single difference in NetBeans at home.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no command that will let you "check out" the whole repository including all the history information, but you *can* simply copy the files if you (or your proxy) have access to the server. A CVS repository is just a directory full of files, and if you make a complete copy of that directory, it acts exactly like the original and could be used to create diffs and change logs as you desire.

Comment: So what you are saying is if I checkout the files (the CVS directory) on to the local hard drive and go offline (take them home) I can see the full history at home?

Comment: No. If you *copy* the repository itself from the server -- i.e., `ssh` onto the server, zip up the repository files, email the zip file to yourself, download the zip on your home machine and unzip it -- then you can use that local copy of the repository to do what you want.

Comment: well I want to be able to search history at home, but there is a firewall that will stop me accessing the cvs itself. and I want to do the searching offline. so that is not at all possible?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible, but you need to make a local copy of the repository, as described above. I'm sorry I'm not making myself understood -- is there something I can explain better?

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated, I am trying my best to understand what you say, but, I can only checkout the project, it checks out a bunch of projects, with two other folders called CVS and CVS ROOT, and my project folder has a folder called CVS in there. will I be able to do history searching offline with these files? thanks alot

Comment: No. You (or someone helping you) needs shell access on the machine where the repository is to copy the files.

Comment: Okay so it's not possible through netbeans itself. Now I understand, what's the very root folder I need to copy over using ssh? thanks.

Comment: by the way, I just checked to see if i can access cvs root (:pserver:user@ip:/directory/)with ssh, but the access is denied, so it doesn't look possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11664/discussion-between-fenerlitk-and-ernest-friedman-hill)